# Passing large integers from Python to C/C++ with scipy.weave.inline

Tags: c++, python, c, scipy, largenumber

I found that a portion of my code written in python could be done faster in C.  I used scipy.weave.inline to do this.  seek_pos, one of the integers that I needed to pass into my C code, was (at times) larger than what could be represented by a 32 bit long.  I could cout seek_pos and get the correct value (maybe 2.3 billion) but when doing other things with it, such as using it as the offset in fseek or fseeko64, it would act as though it were -1.9 billion (or whatever value you'd get from wrapping past the range of positive long ints and around into the negative long ints).

MY WORKAROUND was to break the large integer down in python y=seek_pos/N, x=seek_pos%N, pass in those smaller numbers and rebuild the larger number in C, seek_pos_off = Y*N+X.  I"m new to both Weave and C/C++.  My code works now but I think this is a pretty ridiculous way of getting there.  Maybe I could have specified a premade or made a custom type converter for weave.inline, but how to do this was not clear to me.

If someone can suggest a better way of doing this, I'd appreciate it, but if not, I wanted to post this anyway so that someone dealing with the same problem might at the very least find my work around when searching.

Here's the relevant portion of my code

```
vtrace = numpy.zeros(len_trace, dtype='short')
c_code = '''
using namespace std;
const char * cc_fpath = filepath.c_str();
FILE * infile;
infile = fopen(cc_fpath, "r");
long seek_pos_off;
long long_multiplier;
long_multiplier = seek_pos_multiplier;
long long_adder;
long_adder = seek_pos_adder;
seek_pos_off = long_multiplier * 2000000000 + long_adder;
fseek(infile, seek_pos_off, SEEK_SET);
for (int n=0; n<len_trace; n++) {
    fread(vtrace+n, data_bytes_per_channel, 1, infile);
    fseek(infile, skip_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
}
fclose(infile);

return_val = 0;
'''
filepath = str(filepath)
seek_pos = int(data_start_pos_in_bytes + start_byte)
seek_pos_multiplier = seek_pos/2000000000
seek_pos_adder = seek_pos%2000000000
weave.inline(c_code, ['vtrace', 'filepath', 'seek_pos_multiplier', 
        'seek_pos_adder', 'len_trace', 'data_bytes_per_channel', 
        'skip_bytes'], headers=['<typeinfo>'])
```

Comment: For starts, I would always make `N` a power of 2. Then multiplication and division with remainder are just a bit shift, which is a lot more efficient. Will think about your question, though.

Comment: what happens if you change your C code so it says `unsigned long` everywhere instead of `long`? And have you looked into the `type_converters` argument to `weave.inline`?

Comment: Thanks for the power of 2 note, I'll make that change.  I'm a bit new here, is there a way for me to mark that comment as helpful?

I haven't tried unsigned long, but I expect it would work for the example I mentioned (2.3 Billion).  Though I mentioned 2.3 billion, I actually need to work with numbers larger then the limits of unsigned long too.

Comment: Oh, I did look into type converter's a bit, but had some trouble making sense of how to use them.  I did find one interesting note in some of the weave source though.  In the code for the long_converter class in weave I found the following comment "# !! long to int conversion isn't safe!"

Comment: If you actually need even larger numbers, then we shouldn't spend too much time on getting longs to work. How did you plan on using those big numbers in C and passing them to `fseek`? Do you want to use `lseek64` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
seek_pos = long(data_start_pos_in_bytes + start_byte)
```

instead of

```
seek_pos = int(data_start_pos_in_bytes + start_byte)
```

That may be it.

Comment: I just gave this a shot. I.e. I made the change you mentioned, added 'seek_pos' to the arguments I pass in inline, and replaced seek_pos_off with seek_pos in fseek. This gives a compilation error: "error: conversion from 'py::object' to 'long int' is ambiguous"

Comment: You're right, I'm getting the same thing in your example. I don't really know what to try next. From what I've seen now, I can highly recommend [Cython](http://www.cython.org) instead of `weave` for what you're doing.